# Azure Databricks & pyspark - substring errors

Tags: python-3.x, azure, dataframe, pyspark, databricks

Getting two errors with my Databricks Spark script with the following line:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(pdDf).withColumn('month', substring(col('dt'), 0, 7))
```

The first one:

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'substr'
```

and

```
NameError: name 'substr' is not defined
```

I wonder what I am doing wrong...

Answer (score 0):

Turned out I had not imported the **pyspark.sql.functions**

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
```